# Android Emulator freezes every 3 seconds

Tags: android, android-emulator

I'm trying to run the Android SDK AVD Emulator on my Windows 10 Machine with an i7-6700K and a Geforce GTX 970. I activated Host GPU and Intel HAXM is operational as well. Performance looks generally good, but for a reason that eludes me the emulator hangs every 3-4 Seconds for about a second, then continues normally. As the effect is hard to describe accurately, I made a short video to illustrate the effect:

https://youtu.be/Dl1pxTRIu_c

As I tried to show in the video, even the virtual keyboard below the actual phone emulation is affected by this "hanging". I already tried deactivating my virus scanner (Avira Free), with no effect. There is also nothing running in the background using too much CPU resources (or, any at all, according to the Windows Taskmanager, the system is jumping between about 6% and 15%). Neither using another SDK image nor another device or resolution seemed to help either.

Any help in improving this is greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Install Intel HAXM from android sdk it speed ups android emulator

For more check out this link 
[Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/why-is-the-android-emulator-so-slow-how-can-we-speed-up-the-android-emulator)

Comment: I believe "and Intel HAXM is operational as well" stated that I already did that, if not: Intel HAXM was the first thing I installed, along with activating VT-x on the processor. As you might see on the video, the performance is absolutely fine for 3 Seconds, then for one second it all but freezes completely, only to return to normal performance after the freeze - so I might be wrong, but IMO this isn't related to any other performance issues posted so far, because I don't *have* performance issues, I have a "freezes every 3 seconds" issue.